# What is a vocabulary in logic

Tags: logic, definition, model-theory

I am reading notes on finite model theory and I came across a notion of a vocabulary. What is it? I tried searching on the internet but did not find anything relevant.

Comment: The non-logical symbols of the language, also called [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) or vocabulary.

Comment: Also called a *language*. We have way too many names for some things. (@MauroALLEGRANZA You should turn your comments into an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

See Leonid Libkin, [Elements of Finite Model Theory](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf), Springer (2012), page 13 :

> **Definition 2.1** A *vocabulary* $σ$ is a collection of constant symbols (denoted $c_1,\ldots, c_n,\ldots$), relation, or predicate, symbols ($P_1,\ldots,P_n,\ldots$) and function symbols ($f_1,\ldots,f_n,\ldots$). Each relation and function symbol has an associated arity.

Is the set of non-logical symbols of the language, also called [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)#Other_conventions).